# prometheus get active connection of nginx

Tags: nginx, prometheus

i want to get the active connection of nginx server.
for this a create a job in prometheus

```
  - job_name: 'my-job'
    metrics_path: /nginx_status
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - mynginxserver:9110
        labels:
          service: nginx
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__metrics_path__]
        regex: 'Active connections: (\d+)'
        target_label: active_connections
```

but in promethus the job is down with this error:

strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "connections:": invalid syntax

the curl:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:9110/nginx_status
```

return this:

```
Active connections: 41
server accepts handled requests
 8172 8172 7216
Reading: 0 Writing: 1 Waiting: 1
```

thanks in advance

I want to get the number of network connections opened by nginx, it may not be the best solution, I have not found another solution, if you know of a better one, thank you in advance.

Comment: Your page doesn't return metrics in the OpenMetrics format. And this **cannot** be fixed with relabeling. You need either something that will be exposing metrics in correct format internally, like [this](https://github.com/knyar/nginx-lua-prometheus), or something that will be scraping your current page and exposing results in OpenMetrics format on a separate address, like [this](https://github.com/vozlt/nginx-module-vts) or [this](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter)